# Incorrect user profile picture being displayed from JS array - How to address this?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Sorry for the long post, but I'm not sure the issue comes across without all the code.

I'm using parse.com and the JavaScript SDK.

The below code is part of my users profile page, it displays their profile picture to them on screen and allows them to change it.

Changing the profile picture works fine and is uploaded as expected. The issue is that on the profile page the profile is taking the first users picture and displaying it on page for any user. Basically its not looking at the current user.

I think that I need to update the query to include something like `var currentUser = Parse.User.current();` and introduce it into my code. Whatever why I try and do this I'm hitting a brick wall. Any help would be great

I'm struggling if this is the case to understand how to change my code to avoid this happening?

```
/////////////////////////Queries the users profile picture and shows on page////////////////////////

var UserProfilePic = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var query = new Parse.Query(UserProfilePic);
query.exists("ProfilePic");
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            imageURLs.push(object.get('ProfilePic').url());
        }
        // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        if (imageURLs.length > 0) {
            $('#profile_pic').attr('src', imageURLs[0]);
        }
        $('#Image01').attr('src', imageURLs[0]); //first image
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});


///////// Saves the users profile image and fields after the #save button is clicked//////

var profileSave = Parse.User.current();

function ProfileSave() {

    var User = Parse.Object.extend("_User");

    var profileSave = Parse.User.current();

    var saveusername = $('#username').val();
    var saveemail = $('#email').val();
    var savegender = $('#gender').val();


    profileSave.set("username", saveusername);
    profileSave.set("email", saveemail);
    profileSave.set("gender", savegender);


    profileSave.save(null, {
        success: function(profileSave) {
            profileSave.save();
            console.log("DONE");
            alert("Profile Saved");
        },
        error: function(profileSave, error) {
            // Fail

        }
    });



}


///////////////Allows the user to upload a profile image and store///////////////////////

$(document).ready(function() {

    var parseAPPID = "XXXXXX";
    var parseJSID = "XXXXXX";

    //Initialize Parse
    Parse.initialize(parseAPPID, parseJSID);

    $("#fileUploadBtn").on("click", function(e) {

        var fileUploadControl = $("#fileUploader")[0];
        if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
            var name = file.name;
            console.log("here goes nothing...");
            var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
            parseFile.save().then(function() {
                console.log("Worked!");
                console.dir(arguments);
                var User = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
                var jobApplication = Parse.User.current();

                jobApplication.set("ProfilePic", parseFile);
                jobApplication.save();

                var profilePhoto = jobApplication.get("ProfilePic");
                console.log("Done");

                //jobApplication.get("ProfilePic").url;

            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.dir(error);
            });
        }

    });


});
```

Comment: is it the imageURLs array, that contains all uploaded files?

Comment: @MoLow yes thats correct

Comment: "A Parse.Query can also be used to retrieve a single object whose id is known, through the get method." https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html As I understand, your need to find a picture id (or you can use user id, I don't know), and then pass it to query.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this in the featured/bounties, even though I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974447/parse-query-not-restricting-results-to-current-user/31974723?noredirect=1#comment51857221_31974723) for you, so here's my copy/pasted answer:

You're not using query.exists() the way you think you are. Also, are you just trying to check to see if the current user has a profile image? Because you can just use the `.has("key")` method of objects, and a user is an object. If this is in cloud code, rather than client code, you may have to fetch the user first.  If it is client code, you should already have an up to date user.

You should not be extending the user object. Not necessary at all. Use the Parse.User object type, so if you're querying for users, do `var query = new Parse.Query( Parse.User );`

So I think what you want is something more like:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
if( user.has("ProfilePic") )
{
    //Do your stuff with the image
    var imageURL = user.get("ProfilePic").url();
    $('#Image01').attr('src', imageURL);
}
else
{
    alert("Error: User does not have a 'ProfilePic' set");
}
```

The way your code is set up, you're just querying through all the users with profilePics and taking the first one.  My code only gets the profilePic of the current user.