# Parse query not restricting results to current user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and the JS SDK.

Why wouldn't this query restrict the results to the current user only? I've used

> query.exists("ProfilePic"), Parse.User.current();

which i thought would do this, but all of my users profile images are being returned in the second part of the query, meaning I have the wrong profile picture for the current user.

Not sure why this is?

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
var user = Parse.User.current();
if( user.has("ProfilePic") )
query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
            imageURLs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                imageURLs.push(object.get('ProfilePic').url());
            }
            // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
            if (imageURLs.length > 0) {
                $('#Image01').attr('src', imageURLs[0]);
            }
                $('#Image01').attr('src', imageURLs[0]); //first image
        },
        error: function(error) {
            // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using query.exists() the way you think you are. Also, are you just trying to check to see if the current user has a profile image? Because you can just use the `.has("key")` method of objects, and a user is an object. If this is in cloud code, rather than client code, you may have to fetch the user first.  If it is client code, you should already have an up to date user.

You should not be extending the user object. Not necessary at all. Use the Parse.User object type, so if you're querying for users, do `var query = new Parse.Query( Parse.User );`

So I think what you want is something more like:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
if( user.has("ProfilePic") )
{
    //Do your stuff with the image
    var imageURL = user.get("ProfilePic").url();
    $('#Image01').attr('src', imageURL);
}
else
{
    alert("Error: User does not have a 'ProfilePic' set");
}
```

Comment: T thanks, ive updated the question - is this how you mean?>

Comment: No.  You have not included any conditions for the query, so it is currently querying for any and all users.  results is going to be an array of your first 1000 users.  Where are you calling this code from, and are you trying to get the current user's profile image or any user's profile image? If it's just the current user's profile image, then you only need the code I have. Editing to include what you need from your success block now.  If you are trying to get the profile image of any certain user, then you'll have to fetch that user. If that's the case, lmk and I'll show you how.

Comment: ok thanks, so its just the profile pic for the current user, so the code as is in your example above. I'm not using cloud code for this section, As there is only one image as well - I wonder if my codes over complex to retrieve it and I should use something like the parse example var profilePhoto = profile.get("photoFile");
$("profileImg")[0].src = profilePhoto.url(); ?

Comment: I've only ever used the javascript API for cloud code, so I've never had to display an image with javascript. But I know on my iOS client code I had to do something vaguely similar to what you have here. This doesn't look overly complex to me. However, if that's an explicit example from Parse, maybe you're better of doing it that way. You'll have to test the two and see if one performs significantly better than the other.

Comment: Cheers Jake, works a treat now - sorry for my limited understanding

Comment: No problem. Everybody starts somewhere.  We truly stand on the shoulders of giants, and it's pretty lonely if you don't help others make the climb up. 

Sorry I'm not more familiar with javascript to offer more specific help.